# mongo find all with field that is object having a specified key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

A mongo db has documents that look like:

```
{
    "_id":  : ObjectId("55cb43e8c78b04f43f2eb503"),
    <some fields>
    "topics": {
        "test/23/result": 149823788,
        "test/27/result": 147862733,
        "input/misc/test": 14672882
    }
}
```

I need to find all documents that have a topics field that contains a particular key.  i.e. find all documents that have a topics.key = "test/27/result"

I've tried a number of things but none work yet, neither attempt below work,
they return no records event though some should match:

```
db.collName.find({"topics.test/27/result": {$exists:true}});
db.collName.find({"topics.test\/27\/result": {$exists:true}});
```

How can I make the query work?

The slash characters are inserted by another process.  They are mqtt topic names.

Comment: which mongodb version you are using??

Comment: first one is working for me
        db.collName.find({"topics.test/27/result": {$exists:true}});

Comment: thanks for your comments.  I found that the problem was the way I was structuring the query.  The working solution is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

I was building the query wrong in my code.  In the example below, evtData.source contains the key name to search for, i.e. 'test/27/result'

The query methodology that works for me is:

```
var query = {};
query['topics.' + evtData.source] = {$exists: true};
db.collName.find(query)
```